# h3 element slips away in mobile device

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a problem with a h3 element on my web page. It looks ok on desktop, but on mobile devices slips away, as you can see in the following screenshots.

the h3 element is in a div which has the following css:

```
.experiental-header {
     position: absolute;
     text-align: center;
     width: 100%;
 }
```

and the h3 element has the following css:

```
.experiental-header h3 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 635px;
    padding: 50px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

[image]

and in mobile device:
[image]

I tried in many ways to solve this problem, but none of them has worked well, I don't have too much experience with responsive media queries.
Can you please help me on this? Thank you!

I edited my question:
Now it displays ok, but the text "Experiental" is not changing font size when in responsive mode, as you can see attached:

I have tried with:

```
 font-size: 3em;
```

but it seems that it is not enough. Can you please advise?
[image]

Comment: check .experiental-header parent class has position:relative and set .experiental-header h3 values pixel to percentage

Comment: Remove `width: 635px` from `.experimental-header h3`, add `left: 0; right: 0;` to `.experimental-header`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Experimental-header h3`apply width in percentages. So it will works well in responsive.

```css
.experiental-header {
     position: absolute;
     text-align: center;
     width: 100%;
 }
.experiental-header h3 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 50px;
    background:green;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.9vw;

    }
```

```html
<div class="experiental-header">
  <h3>Heading-3</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: - I've edited the question. Can you please advise? The text Experiental is not changing his size in responsive mode. Thanks in advance!

Comment: apply font-size in percentages.

Comment: I've tried with font-size: 3em;, but it did not resolved

Comment: I updated snippet.Try to apply font-size like this `font-size: 2.9vw`